# Angular module failed because of improper loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, dependencies, loading

I am using the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project as an example for my own project.

I create the app module in `app.js`, like the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

```
"use strict";

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "myApp.home"])
.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
}]);
```

I then create my `myApp.home` in another file.

```
"use strict";

angular.module("myApp.home", ["ngRoute"])

.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "views/home/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
  });
}])

.controller("HomeController", [function() {

}]);
```

I load the two in my `index.html` file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="views/home/home.js"</script>
```

Angular cannot instantiate the app because `myApp.home` is not available. I assume this is because I am loading `app.js` first. And it is looking for `myApp.home` which is not loaded yet.

> Is this something Angular should be taking care of, or do I need to
>   create a build process?

After reading online, I cannot find a solution that works for me, maybe I am overlooking something silly.

Comment: Is the missing `>` a typo in the post only?

Comment: Also, I see app.js, but where is the file for myApp.home? Also, how are you bootstrapping the application? Through ng-app or angular.bootstrap?

Comment: @MatthewGreen that was the issue, I am a doofus. Thanks!

Comment: It happens. The highlighting gave it away. Maybe you need a new editor?

Comment: @MatthewGreen just started using Atom, and only the closing `script` tag changed from red to orange. Just didn't notice it.